# bubble.io Question: API/raw HTTP post access?

Tags: post, http-post

I'm working on getting a Bubble API connection set up. I'm trying to make an API POST call using json to a REST API and it’s saying I haven’t actually sent any parameters in my JSON. Does anyone familiar with Bubble know how I can see the raw HTTP post that Bubble is sending?